# Iphone 6 & 6++ not receiving push notifications

Tags: ios, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have developed IOS app and it is published in app store. When i am sending push notification from back end (using php script) only iphone5 & iphone5s users are getting the notification. Both of these phones are having IOS 8 installed.

iphone6 & iphone6+ devices not receiving any push notifications, all my devices are having same ios version 'ios8.1.3'. I also updated iphone6+ to ios 8.2 but nothing.

I have tried various things such as resetting the notification dialogue etc.. but nothing has helped so far.

Is there any solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show me the code for push notification.

Comment: I know it might sound stupid, but each time I install my app on iPhone 6+, it automatically turns off the push notifications in the app setup, for no reason. It's worth the try to look in the phone's settings.

Comment: @user1116101 Did you get solution for this?

Comment: Did you get solution for this?